# Adding a custom category - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c-category

I am having trouble adding my custom `uicolor`

I have a `.h` and a `.m` file, both named `custcolors`

Here is what my `custColors.h` file looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (MyCatagory)
+ (UIColor*) customRedColor;
@end
```

Here is what my `custColors.m` file looks like:

```
#import "custColors.h"

@implementation UIColor (MyCategory)

+ (UIColor *)customRedColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"88C800"];
}
-(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];

    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];

    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];

    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                           alpha:1.0f];
}

@end
```

My issue is that when I try to use this I just get an error.  Saying;

```
custColors.h:12:33: Expected identifier
custColors.h:12:35: Expected an Objective-C directive after '@'
custColors.m
custColors.m:13:51: Use of undeclared identifier 'hex'
```

What I am trying to do is create a custom hex color that I can use to be able to implement into every view controller to change it's background color to this.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Look at what you did. You have weird mashup of the two methods merged together. Create two separate methods just like any other methods.

Comment: You have spelled the name of the category two different ways. They must match exactly!

Comment: Here check update I changed it...

Comment: You need to `#import "UIColor+MyCategory.h"` instead you are importing `custColors.h`. Also, naming a class like that is a serious violation of `Objective-C` coding rules

Comment: @unspokenblabber why do I need to use `UIColor+MyCategory.h` instead of `UIColor+custColors.h`?

Comment: Because, that is the name of your category. See `UIColor (MyCatagory)`

Comment: @unspokenblabber No, the name of the .h file is `custColors.h`. The name of the file does not have to match the name of the category. Though that is a common convention.

Comment: @DavidBiga Please point out clearly which line of code is giving you the problem. We can't be sure about the line numbers.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree.
I don't see a problem with your code. I was actually able to do a test run and I must say this is a very useful piece of code.

Comment: @maddy okay so I changed the `colorWithHexString` to a class method as karwag suggested and it works so where I am stuck on is `#import "UIColor+custColors.h"` should I be importing with just the header file or what?  also when wanting to use this custom color in the `MyCategory` how do I set that to all of my view controllers?

Comment: @DavidBiga Change your `#import` so the filename matches your the filename of your actual .h file. And may I suggest you stop your iOS development for a short time and spend some time working with some basic Objective-C tutorials. You need to learn and understand the basic language before you try to write an app. The time spent now will save you a lot time (and SO questions) down the road.

Comment: @maddy I know but I am learning as I follow the tutorial and do stuff I actually figured it out.  I just simply change my viewcontrollers in the storyboard to contain the class I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that colorWithHexString should be a class method, not an instance method.
Change it to:

```
+ (UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex {

    ...
}
```